# ioS7: Capture multiple images from camera and store in array

Tags: ios, objective-c

guys.

I'm trying to capture multiple images from the camera in iOS7, when I capture the first image and click in in "Use Photo", then it's store the image in a array in didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo. When the camera appear again, I see the last image in background but I can't see the camera movement. I know the camera is enabled, because it's searching faces. The code is below:

```
 - (IBAction)openTour:(id)sender
 {
      _counter=0;

      if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
      {
           UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
           imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
           imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
           imagePicker.delegate = self;
           [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];
           imagePicker = nil;
       }
 }

 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:  (NSDictionary *)info
 {
     UIImage *image= [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];

     [ _imageArray addObject:image ];

     _counter++;

     if ( _counter<5 )
     {
          [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

          if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
          {
               UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
               imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
               imagePicker.showsCameraControls = YES;
               imagePicker.delegate = self;
               [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO completion:nil];
               imagePicker = nil;
          }
     }
     else
     {
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
     }
 }
```

Does anyone know what is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Set showsCameraControls = NO;

Use `cameraOverlayView` property.

In the action of your camera button call `takePicture` method.
Keep adding UIImage objects received by the method

```
    -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, Sarvjeet. Sorry, I'm a beginner programmer objective-c. Could you explain it in other way? Thanks, friend!

Comment: You can read here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html